# Slow Internet connection with 11.04

Tags: 11.04, drivers, internet, broadcom

My internet connection is extremely slow after installing 11.04, It took me over night to download and install firefox flash player pluggin. I have a laptop on the same network which is running windows7 and the speed from that is extremely fast.
Update manager is showing 10.1kb/s. This is really surreal.

I have done some googling around and noticed others having the same problem recommend the command below to do the trick:

```
sudo -s
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
reboot
```

I am not using Atheros wire/wireless card. My machine is installed with Broadcom Gigabit Ethernet card. Do anyone know how to resolve this issue.

I have done some search around here, and found a few post which seems to experience the same issue - but none of the suggested solution seems to help.

When i run `lspci`, i get below output.

> ```
> 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation E7230/3000/3010 Memory Controller Hub (rev 81) 
> 00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation E7230/3000/3010 PCI Express Root Port (rev 81) 
> 00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 01) 
> 00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GR/GH/GHM (ICH7 Family) PCI Express Port 6 (rev 01) 
> 00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01) 
> 00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 01) 
> 00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 01) 
> 00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01) 
> 00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev e1) 
> 00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR (ICH7 Family) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01) 
> 00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller (rev 01) 
> 00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation N10/ICH7 Family SATA IDE Controller (rev 01) 
> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation GT216 [GeForce GT 220] (rev a2) 
> 01:00.1 Audio device: nVidia Corporation High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
> **07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5721 Gigabit Ethernet PCI** Express (rev 11)
> ```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/46836/internet-is-often-very-slow-in-natty

Comment: Downloading Flash may be slow because you hit a slow mirror. Test your connection with http://speedtest.net to make sure it's really slow.

Comment: I have followed the instruction from the link above and no joy. installing application take extremely long time. Ubuntu software centre installations are extremely slow.

Comment: Do you think rollback to 10 will be any good?

Comment: @bitmap - you perhaps need more details about your card (lspci, lshw) etc - are you talking about a wireless card or a wired connection?  If a wireless card, does this solution work for your?/  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1604868&page=22

Comment: @fossfreedom  I am using a wired card. This machine use to run windows and the connection was fine.

Comment: I have added more detail about my card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of struggling with my connection speed, I finally decide I go down to the port level to investigate. Both my phone and ADSL were going via the same micro-filter. I had a spare phone port and micro-filter available therefore I have seperated the phone and ADSL to have their own independent telephone port, each connected through a micro-filter.

I then phone my provider to made a little fuss - now I am back to the super rocket speed again.

Thanks all for your support.