# Wired internet speed is slow in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: internet-connection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Internet very slow in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106290/internet-very-slow-in-ubuntu)

I have dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 on my Dell N4110 laptop.
I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my existing windows 7 hard drive. I am experiencing very slow internet speed on Ubuntu(wired connection). But on Windows,internet is really fast. I disabled ipv6
by editing  `/etc/sysctl.conf` No avail. Then i run the following command.

```
sudo ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex full autoneg off
```

No benefit.

I am having "Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)" network card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are having slow internet speeds when downloading packages you can do this:

1)Open the software center

2)Go to Edit>Software Sources

3)Under "Ubuntu Software", click the dropdown list labeled "Download from".

4)Click "Other".

5)Now click "Select Best Server".

It will run tests and come up with the server that is right for your location. If it is an issue with slow browsing speeds not related to the Ubuntu servers make sure your browser is up to date.

Comment: This only applies to downloading software through the Ubuntu repositories. He may do more with his Internet connection than download packages.

Comment: He said he had slow Internet speed under Ubuntu. Selecting a better repo server doesn't address the issue of why Ubuntu seems to be making his system perform more slowly. Moreover, it won't do anything to improve any type of traffic except package downloading which is presumably the least of his concerns (I've never met or heard of anyone who uses the Internet exclusively to download packages). It seems altogether irrelevant to the problem, which is why I downvoted. Not trying to be rude or condescending, it just doesn't add up IMHO.

Comment: I showed it to one of my friend who is a software developer. I don't know what he did.Now, my internet is properly on my Ubuntu.I can update and download packages with fast internet speeds.

Comment: @RameshKatkam if he solved your problem can you get him to list it as an answer, it doesn't help accepting something that didn't solve the problem if he solved it another way.

Comment: @mateo_salta In my case,I have an 100 Mb/s ethernet connection.Most of the time, I get only 10 Mb/s when i start my Ubuntu 12.04.I i get only 10 Mb/s,I simply disconnect the network with this command                        sudo ifconfig eth0 down                                                                                    Then i reconnect the network with    sudo ifconfig eth0 up                            Now,I get 100 Mb/s speed.I have to execute these commands everytime i start my Ubuntu 12.04.I don't  the permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.04 is slower than Windows 7 in network performance. Testing both, it's about 50% or less. With Dell Optiplex 780 and Intel 82567LM-3 adapter, the number of collisions in a 12 hour period 11479. Tried 1000/100 mbit with full and half duplex. No change. Going to try tcp windows size adjustments. Never had this issue when the same system had Windows 2008 server. Recently switched to 12.04 LTS on the same system and network performance slowed to a crawl. I cannot find an updated 82567LM-3 driver so I am currently stuck with this issue.

Comment: @EliahKagan I may have misunderstood the answer. Sorry to the poster and I hope I have not discouraged you from using this site.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install preload` works pretty well.