# Ubuntu 12.10 Slow Download Speed

Tags: 12.10, networking, download-speed

I'm using ubuntu 12.10. Although system is quite fast, I have a very slow download speed.
Can anyone help me to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/106290/internet-very-slow-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a reference speed to go by?  It may not be related to Ubuntu at all.  If you have another operating system or another computer to compare against you might be able to narrow down if its Ubuntu or your router/modem.

Answer (score -2):

Try using IDM (Internet Download Manager).

1. If download speed is still slow, it could indicate a problem with your network configuration OR a problem with your internet connection.
2. If IDM is not compatible with Ubuntu, try downloading and installing "Wine" (to run Windows apps) and try again.

Comment: IDM will not work in Ubuntu