# Slow wireless with an Intel 4965

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless

I just installed 12.04LTS and the wifi became extremely slow. 
When I booted back to windows the wifi became normal again. 
This happened the first time when I upgraded 10.10 to 11.04, so I stopped using Ubuntu for a year, hoping this will be solved by 12.04. 
Of course it didn't, so I googled for the fix but nothing seems to work.

I've already tried the three methods in this site:

- http://www.unixmen.com/resolve-slow-connexion-when-using-wifi-in-ubuntu-1104-natty-narwhal/

Oh, I forgot to say that the internet was normal when I connected it to wired.
But, I'm still having issues with my Wifi.

***Hardware Specs***

My computer model is **Asus M70Sa** and the wifi card is **802.11abgn+BT**

Here is the whole list of them when I typed "sudo lspci -nn" into *Konsloe*:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Mobile PM965/GM965/GL960 Memory Controller Hub [8086:2a00] (rev 03)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Mobile PM965/GM965/GL960 PCI Express Root Port [8086:2a01] (rev 03)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 [8086:2834] (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 [8086:2835] (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 [8086:283a] (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller [8086:284b] (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 1 [8086:283f] (rev 03)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 3 [8086:2843] (rev 03)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 4 [8086:2845] (rev 03)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 5 [8086:2847] (rev 03)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 6 [8086:2849] (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 [8086:2830] (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 [8086:2831] (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 [8086:2832] (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 [8086:2836] (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge [8086:2448] (rev f3)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation 82801HM (ICH8M) LPC Interface Controller [8086:2815] (rev 03)
00:1f.1 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) IDE Controller [8086:2850] (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:2829] (rev 03)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV635 [Mobility Radeon HD 3650] [1002:9591]
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV635 HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 3600 Series] [1002:aa20]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8055 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller [11ab:4363] (rev 13)
06:00.0 SATA controller [0106]: JMicron Technology Corp. JMB360 AHCI Controller [197b:2360] (rev 02)
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 4965 AG or AGN [Kedron] Network Connection [8086:4229] (rev 61)
08:01.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394) [0c00]: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller [1180:0832] (rev 05)
08:01.1 SD Host controller [0805]: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter [1180:0822] (rev 22)
08:01.2 System peripheral [0880]: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter [1180:0592] (rev 12)
08:01.3 System peripheral [0880]: Ricoh Co Ltd xD-Picture Card Controller [1180:0852] (rev 12)
```

**Update: May 12, 2012**

I just installed the madwifi-0.9.4-current driver for my Atheros card, but after I rebooted, nothing appears to have been changed. Also I have no idea how to configure the Atheros card, or even if it was installed or not.

**Update: May 13, 2012**

I just tried another solution in form: [Why is my internet so slow with an Atheros wireless card?](https://askubuntu.com/q/37409/61067)
It did speed up by connection just by a little bit, but I was still getting less than 15% of my normal connection speed.

**Update: May 17, 2012**

Does anyone know why is causing this problem? Because, form what I've heard, other distros aren't having this issue (except Linux Mint, but it is based on Ubuntu).

- Could it be driver problem?
- Or some kind of incompatibility between the Ubuntu 12.04 and the driver?
- Or the driver support is outdated?
- Other possibilities?

*Part 2*

Ok, so I went to the library and the wifi became normal.

- Could it be a router problem/incompatibility?
- Internet provider? I doubt it, because using Wifi on Windows was normal.

**Update: May 18, 2012**

 I do not know what happened, but somehow my wifi is fixed. Does it have anything to do with the update just few hours ago? 

Well...It did work for a bit, but returned to the unbearably-laggy-wifi about after 45mins.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this will work for you, but you may try and switch off power management for your wireless (it has helped others apparently). Open a terminal and type the following:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

Hit Enter. This is assuming that your wireless is labeled as wlan0. To check, in an open terminal simply type:

```
iwconfig
```

It should list three things such as lo, wlan0 and eth0 although they may be labeled differently. Also, it would help if you could type in:

```
lspci
```

This will allow us to ascertain what wireless chip you are using.
If by switching off the power management works, then to make it permanent follow the instructions given by sagarchalise here:

[How can I prevent iwconfig power management from being turned on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85214/how-can-i-prevent-iwconfig-power-management-from-being-turned-on/129634#129634)

Answer (score 1):

I just installed 12.04LTS too.
I have a HP Pavilion dv7.
First solution on www.unixmen.com/resolve-slow-connexion-when-using-wifi-in-ubuntu-1104-natty-narwhal/ worked.

Note: The file didn't exist but in the empty file I typed what was asked.

Restarting the system did the job. I now have again 50Mb/s download on my ISP connection which is what I pay for.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Nice, however, the first solution has nothing to do with Intel wireless. :~)

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, Sony Vaio VFN-FZ31E with Intel 4965 wifi card. I tried different methods but only got results compiling an old kernel.

I used 2.6.32.27, the last kernel for 10.04:
http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/linux-2.6.32.27.tar.bz2

Follow this instructions to compile:
http://mitchtech.net/compile-linux-kernel-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-detailed/

If you get `gcc: error: elf_i386: No such file or directory`, error you should make a change in the kernel source, in `arch/x86/vdso/Makefile` as follows:

*replace* `-m elf_x86_64` with `-m64` on the line starting with  `VDSO_LDFLAGS_vdso.lds`
*replace* `-m elf_x86` with `-m32` on the line starting with  `VDSO_LDFLAGS_vdso32.lds`

Don't forget to select this kernel in grub at startup.

Answer (score -1):

If you have the proprietary Broadcom drivers installed it might be the problem. Once I removed the proprietary driver I got my regular slow DSL back!

Answer (score -1):

First connect to the internet via your wired internet cable.

Then go to http://madwifi-project.org/ to install the Atheros Drivers.