# internet ridiculously slow on Ubuntu where as its very fast on Windows 7 in the same machine

Tags: internet

I recently installed Ubuntu in my machine which already has Windows 7. Internet pages load really fast  when I boot Windows 7, but its very very slow and sometimes wont even load in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I tried several solutions mentioned online but nothing works. My settings use IPV4 not IPV6. Please help.

Comment: I have the same problem as yours. I'm currently investigating it and I believe it has something to do with our routers. Because when I took my computer to the library, the wifi became normal again. Also it will be best to list your system specs. Here's how to do it: 1. Go to Terminal 2. Type `sudo lspci -nn` 3. Hit enter 4. Then come back and paste your results 5. Paste your results, select it and hit ctrl-k (It'll format it for you) PS. Try plugging your computer to an ethernet cable for the moment, it might help <br>(That's what I do when I'm home) You might also want to look at my page: htt

Comment: Could you let us know: are they installed on the same drive?  Is it a traditional HDD with the Ubuntu partition at the end?  What is your network connectivity, do you connect to a home router and use no interesting config such as a proxy?

Comment: The question description here is very different from the description in http://askubuntu.com/questions/21307/slow-internet-browsing-in-ubuntu. Which (if either) is most similar to the problem you're experiencing. Unless you feel totally sure that you have exactly the same problem as has been posted about in an existing question, you should strongly consider posting your own question. If it's found to be the same, it can always be closed as a duplicate of an existing question.

Comment: ...Or are you saying that http://askubuntu.com/questions/132317/slow-wireless-with-an-intel-4965 is the problem you're having that you think is like this and http://askubuntu.com/questions/21307/slow-internet-browsing-in-ubuntu. If so, that doesn't seem particularly similar to me, since that problem of yours has as one of its most salient features that it definitively happens only when you connect to the Internet via your wireless connection.

Comment: Well, it is still unclear whether lak's slow connection happens only if connected through wifi or not. I have already told laks to test it out. If that is the case, laks might have the same issue as me.

Comment: Neon, thanks for your reply, yes they are installed on the same drive. Yes it is a traditional HDD with Ubuntu partition at the end. I am not using any proxy. I think the following reply from Kevin provided me some direction.

Comment: Kevin, you might be right, my wired connection works without ant problem. I did not try external WIFI, will try this weekend. If it is router problem(ASUS router) how to solve it?? looks more interesting. I have another stand alone Ubuntu machine which is perfectly fine. Only this instance of Ubuntu which I installed from windows 7 have problems connecting to internet. the following are my lspci results.

Comment: 00:1f.6 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem [8086:3b32] (rev 05)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57780 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1692] (rev 01)
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Atheros Communications Inc. AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002a] (rev 01)
ff:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers [8086:2c62] (rev 02)

Comment: Well, I'm still in the process of finding the fix myself, but I'll tell you as soon as I find the fix. This is really intresting because I also dual boot form Win7 and we both use Intel Wirless cards.

Comment: If you are posting and you dont have a fix that will answer the question, your post is not necessarily an answer, Kevin. Both of you, in the mean time, open up the "Hardware Drivers" tool to find additional drivers, because your wifi is an Atheros card, not an Intel card.

Comment: Although there are 5 deleted answers to this question it is an unanswered question about Ubuntu 12.04 which EOL. The last comment was 5+ years ago by @ThomasWard and the OP appears to have abandoned the question. Even though the question is protected by Community, all things considered VTC as `not reproducible`