# Ubuntu 14.04 Slow and unstable wifi connection

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking

After installing Ubuntu 14.04, the connection frequently drops. I tried to fix the problem by myself but I made things worse, I run this code I read in another article which made my connection really slow.

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv iwlwifi
sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi

sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off

$ lspci -nn | grep 0280
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01)
```

Can you help me fix this?

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless card from the terminal: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Thanks.

Comment: ok , one moment plz

Comment: Updating only the kernel to 3.16 did the trick for me. Info here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/506956/how-can-i-install-3-16-kernel-on-ubuntu-14-04v

Comment: what does a curl analyze say? http://askubuntu.com/a/147385/378854 Are you sure the internet itself is to blame, not the DNS lookups?

Answer (score 3):

You haven't an iwlwifi device or driver, so it is unlikely that iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 did anything. Please check here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1310512 Notice it is your same 10ec:8179 device. Comment #30, it says:

> Tips for RTL8188EE [10ec:8179] and RTL8723BE [10ec:b723] users: those
>   hardware modules have MSI compatibility issue, on some certain
>   platforms they work fine with MSI but break connections without MSI,
>   on some other certain platforms it's opposite. You could try to toggle
>   its module parameter "msi"

Let's try the driver parameter:

```
sudo -i
echo "options rtl8188ee msi=1"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8188ee.conf
exit
```

Reboot and tell us if stability is improved.

Comment: yes the stability has improved , so the codes i used earlier didn't do anything , should i do something for the speed ?

Comment: What speeds are you getting and what do you expect?

Comment: @Tsakras I will be very glad to help further. Please tell us what speeds are you getting and what you hoped for.

Comment: You solved a problem I was facing over a week. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Blauhirn The command I suggested creates it.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the n-mode and updating only the kernel to 3.16 did the trick for me.

N-mode: `echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`

Kernel update: [How can I install 3.16 kernel on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506956/how-can-i-install-3-16-kernel-on-ubuntu-14-04v)

Comment: indeed, updating to 3.16 helped!

Comment: This answer is not related to the question about the Realtek adapter at all.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the problem persists when downloading a large file. If not, the problem might be http-request-side only, see https://askubuntu.com/a/147385/378854. You might have messed up your namespaces (resolv.conf).

Other than that, reinstalling the wifi driver might work:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r) linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms git 
git clone https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu-fixes
sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.9
echo "blacklist rtl8192cu" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

As of April 2016, the needed install cmd is `8192cu/1.10` (just check the latest version)

Or you might update your kernel manually to a newer version (not really difficult)