# Ubuntu 14 - WIFI unstable and slow with rtl8723be

Tags: wireless, networking

I have a very similar problem with this post:

[Ubuntu 14.04 Slow and unstable wifi connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551068/ubuntu-14-04-slow-and-unstable-wifi-connection/551081#551081)

But I could not comment there and that's why I'm asking a new question.

I have a notebook with dual boot windows 8 / ubuntu 14. My wifi internet works just fine in windows but it is very slow and unstable in ubuntu: the conection drops every 5 minutes or so.

I've tried a lot of different solutions (including upgrading kernel to 3.17.1). I've also tried the solution proposed by Chili555 in the link above (but changing "rtl8188ee" for "rtl8723be") and nothing seems to work.

Here are some informations about my notebook

```
 $sudo lshw -C network
 *-network               
       descrição: Ethernet interface
       produto: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       fabricante: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       ID físico: 0
       informações do barramento: pci@0000:08:00.0
       nome lógico: eth0
       versão: 07
       serial: 34:64:a9:75:ff:7a
       tamanho: 10Mbit/s
       capacidade: 100Mbit/s
       largura: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuração: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       recursos: irq:41 porta de E/S:5000(tamanho=256) memória:b5600000-b5600fff memória:b5400000-b5403fff

  *-network
       descrição: Interface sem fio
       produto: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       fabricante: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       ID físico: 0
       informações do barramento: pci@0000:0a:00.0
       nome lógico: wlan0
       versão: 00
       serial: 10:08:b1:3b:3d:11
       largura: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuração: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=3.17.1-031701-generic firmware=N/A ip=10.110.80.14 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       recursos: irq:46 porta de E/S:3000(tamanho=256) memória:b5500000-b5503fff


$ifconfig -a

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW 34:64:a9:75:ff:7a  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          pacotes RX:0 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 quadro:0
          Pacotes TX:0 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 portadora:0
          colisões:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Loopback Local  
          inet end.: 127.0.0.1  Masc:255.0.0.0
          endereço inet6: ::1/128 Escopo:Máquina
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Métrica:1
          pacotes RX:156 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 quadro:0
          Pacotes TX:156 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 portadora:0
          colisões:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:11241 (11.2 KB) TX bytes:11241 (11.2 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW 10:08:b1:3b:3d:11  
          inet end.: 10.110.80.14  Bcast:10.110.255.255  Masc:255.255.0.0
          endereço inet6: fe80::1208:b1ff:fe3b:3d11/64 Escopo:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          pacotes RX:19710 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 quadro:0
          Pacotes TX:1455 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 portadora:0
          colisões:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2757117 (2.7 MB) TX bytes:218735 (218.7 KB)



$nm-tool

State: connecting

- Device: wlan0  [SmartCampus] -------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            rtl8723be
  State:             connecting (configuring)
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        10:08:B1:3B:3D:11

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points 
    Tatane:          Infra, 00:26:F2:52:53:D7, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 30 WPA WPA2
    JH cherche JF plutot canon: Infra, 88:9F:FA:0F:E7:35, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 40 WEP
   NUMERICABLE-6B42:Infra, 24:EC:99:FF:A8:CB, Freq 2452 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 40 WPA WPA2
    SmartCampus:     Infra, E0:1C:41:AB:80:54, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 35
    NUMERICABLE-1AB1:Infra, 00:1A:2B:9B:1F:01, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 37 WPA WPA2
    Livebox-1E06:    Infra, 40:F2:01:5E:1E:06, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 34 WPA WPA2
    NUMERICABLE-CAAC:Infra, 00:1A:2B:6C:B1:DC, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 44 WEP
    FreeWifi:        Infra, 14:0C:76:70:C5:82, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 57
    SFR WiFi FON:    Infra, AA:17:33:E0:E7:91, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 74
    SmartCampus:     Infra, E0:1C:41:AB:7F:94, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 100


- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        34:64:A9:75:FF:7A

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off
```

Comment: PS. You can select a pasted text and press CTRL+K to show it in monospace font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please open a terminal and do:

```
echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=N ips=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

Reboot and tell us if the wireless is working as expected.

In case of further trouble, please run the wireless script as described here: [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180) As the output is lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link in you response: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: I did as proposed and in the last 2 hours the internet is working just fine. If it continues like that after a few reboots, I'll consider the problem solved. Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: Ok, it was working just fine until yesterday. Today, it simple stopped working. I can connect to my wifi network but I can't connect to the internet. Any ideas? The problem only happens in Ubuntu.

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Answer (score 2):

On top of it, if your wifi keeps disconnecting, the problem lies with the Ubuntu Kernel and all you need to do is 2 things:

1. [Update to latest kernel which is 3.17](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2014/11/how-to-install-linux-kernel-3-17-3-in-linux.html):

   > **Download .deb packages:**
   >
   > - For 32-bit systems:
   >
   >   ```
   >   $ wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.17.3-vivid/linux-headers-3.17.3-031703_3.17.3-031703.201411141335_all.deb
   >   $ wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.17.3-vivid/linux-headers-3.17.3-031703-generic_3.17.3-031703.201411141335_i386.deb
   >   $ wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.17.3-vivid/linux-image-3.17.3-031703-generic_3.17.3-031703.201411141335_i386.deb
   >   ```
   > - For 64-bit systems:
   >
   >   ```
   >   $ wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.17.3-vivid/linux-headers-3.17.3-031703_3.17.3-031703.201411141335_all.deb
   >   $ wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.17.3-vivid/linux-headers-3.17.3-031703-generic_3.17.3-031703.201411141335_amd64.deb
   >   $ wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.17.3-vivid/linux-image-3.17.3-031703-generic_3.17.3-031703.201411141335_amd64.deb
   >   ```
   >
   > **Install and reboot:**
   >
   > ```
   > $ sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.17.3*.deb linux-image-3.17.3*.deb; sudo reboot
   > ```
2. Download the latest **rtl8723be** drivers

There is a new version of this driver at GitHub.
You will need to have the package with the kernel headers installed.

```
git clone http://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```

This version of the driver will be submitted for inclusion in kernel 3.18.

Comment: The latest kernel is actually 3.18.4 so if it was indeed included the driver should already be in the newest available kernel. That aside, while it is generally a good idea to post your sources, any answer should contain all relevant information so that it can still be useful even if the linked pages are not available.