# Random DNS lookup time

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. My problem appeared last week.

My DNS lookups randomly takes 15.525 seconds. But once in a while, it will be very fast like it used to be.

I've been using [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/147385/699492) solution to monitor the timings.

Here is an exemple of the results i have :

```
  DNS lookup                          :  15,525
  Connect to server (TCP)             :  15,543
  Connect to server (HTTP/S)          :  0,000
  Time from start until transfer began:  15,544
  Time for redirection (if any)       :  0,000
  Total time before transfer started  :  15,557

         Total time                   :  15,557
         Size of download (bytes)     :  266
         Average d/l speed (bytes/s)  :  17,000
```

When i try a DNS request like this, 3 cases might happens:

- it taks a few millisconds like it should

or

- it takes **exactly** 15.525 seconds

... which makes me think that something is causing a delay. However, i've been trying  to solve this for 2 days and cannot what is causing the delay. I know that the problem is software related since my coworkers have no issue and we are on the same switch.

Here is the the content of `/etc/resolv.conf` :

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

.. and the content of `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` :

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
#dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

Thank you for your help, I'm having a hard time working in this conditions!

EDIT:

Result of `nmcli dev show enp2s0 | grep -i dns` :

```
IP4.DNS[1]:                             8.8.8.8
IP4.DNS[2]:                             8.8.4.4
```

Content of /`etc/network/interfaces`

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Result of `tail /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/*` :

```
==> /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head <==
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
tail: cannot open '/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/original' for reading: No such file or directory

==> /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail
```

Result of `dig google.com`

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 63228
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: Message has 4 extra bytes at end

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     60  IN  A   216.58.204.142

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Fri Oct 20 15:59:06 CEST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 48
```

Result of `cat /etc/nsswitch.conf` :

```
passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files
```

Result of `cat /etc/hosts` :

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   pelomeduda
127.0.0.1   // sorry cannot show this (company name)


# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: What a strange error. Did you check all the locations for futher DNS servers which might be configured? `nmcli dev list iface <interfacename>`, `/etc/network/interfaces` and `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/*`?

Comment: Thanks @malte ,

I edited my post with the results. What should i look for in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d`? I have 4 files: `base`, `head`, `original`, and `tail`

Comment: `tail /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/*` should be sufficient. Do you also use IPv6? Full disclosure: I'm fishing in the dark here. ;)

Comment: @Malte no problem, i really appreciate your help.
I disabled IPv6 yesterday, but it did not solve anything.

I also noticed that `dig` seems to be working properly! It uses 8.8.4.4 (Google) as a DNS.

Comment: That's even more strange. Does it work all the time? If so it might have something todo with the configuration for the `http` database in your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and the `/etc/hosts` file. But this is also a wild guess.

Comment: When i try with `dig @8.8.4.4` it always work (few millisec), while when i use `dig @8.8.8.8` it's pretty random, but most of the time very slow

Comment: Well, it looks like i fixed it. I went to gnome settings and triedto switch to OpenDNS. I didn't workanymore so i switched back to 8.8.4.4, and now everything is working. I have absolutely no idea why :o I'll will wait a little bit before closing this post to be sure. Anyway, i can't thank you enough for your time!

Comment: Yeah! Glad to “help”. One last question: have you tried a reboot? ;)

Comment: Yes, multiple times!

Comment: Ok, ok. Just wanted to ask. ;) Enjoy you fast DNS resolving.