# First website load is slow. Subsequent requests are fast

Tags: networking

First website load is slow. Subsequent requests are fast. I changed dns to google's ones but it's still the same. Browser: Google Chrome.

Comment: Could you use the developer tool - network profiling in chrome and see what slowing it down? You may also check if DNS are fast enough using `dig google.com` & `time dig google.com` not precise but give you an idea at least.

Comment: are you running a local bind instance or other dns cache? Is IPv6 configured (it can slow down resolution of DNS if IPv4 only) Running tthe same dig command twice will give a clue - if time drops to 0 there is a local dns cache happening. Do you mean for the same site or for different sites?

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192775/slow-loading-time-of-pages-visited-for-first-time

Answer (score 2):

This is because Chrome/Chromium caches some of the website assets. You can check the parts of the website that are cached by opening the 'Network' tab in the Developer Tools. This also applies to Firefox (which is what I use myself).

If you enabled DNS caching manually, that may also be the reason for subsequent requests being faster.